# Find instant in which diode starts conducting in transformer full wave rectifier

Tags: voltage, diodes, transformer, rectifier

We have the following circuit

[image]

V2 = Vs/a;

a = 10;

Vs = 100sin(wt);

w = 200 rad/s;

> Each of the diodes is
>   modeled by a fixed 0.8 V drop when conducting, and by an open circuit when OFF. Find the
>   first time instant (in ms) when diode D1 starts conducting.

I know that for a diode to be conducting there vL should have a voltage equal or higher than V2.

By KVL I found that vL = 9.2 V and put 10sin(wt) = 9.2, and solved it to get t = 0.335 (ms).

The answer however is 0.4 (ms).

What did I do wrong and how should I proceed?

Comment: your secondary SLEWRATE is 2,000 volts per second. To swing 0.8 volts will need 0.8/2000 = 0.0004 seconds approximately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the instant in which the diode starts conducting, its current will be vanishingly small. So vL will be zero. Then v2 will be 0.8 volts.

Assume that Vs = 2 v2, since the transformer is overall 1:1, and solve for v2 = 0.8.

Comment: Mr Sinno... In real world , we say Vf=0.8V @ If= (Vs-0.8)/R which is more than the vanish point or near 0, so the time delay to reach this voltage at some phase is actually a tad larger.  Vf=0.8 is 1A for a typ. 1N4005 power diode. but for now neglect this.

Comment: Mr Roughbeast. Now for an expert question. ( for fun) What transformer parameters (L=?, coupling coefficient=?) with at least 1 sig.fig) are necessary to achieve  Vf=0.8A say for 1kOhm load and what must be the PIV rating.? (min)

Comment: For Uber Analog EE's, what is the diode bulk resistance, Rs  for that PIV diode to conduct enough current to reach 0.8V  ?  to at least 1 sig.fig.

Comment: Uber Answer: No solution as Diodes do not have a Peak Inverse Voltage rating of >=10kV with a forward Vf=0.8. It would have to be at least 10 diodes in 1 thus Vf >8V so not possible to have Vf=0.8V with Vr=10kV=PIV rating

Answer (score 2):

\$10sin(\omega t)=0.8\$

\$sin(\omega t)=0.08\$

\$arcsin(0.08)=\omega t=0.080086\:rad\$

\$\therefore \:t=0.080086/200=0.40043\: ms\:\approx 0.4 \:ms\$

Note: \$sin(\theta)\approx\theta\:\$  for small values of \$\theta\$, where \$\theta\$ is in radians. So we could get to the approximate answer without doing the \$arcsin\$.

Comment: good use of Trigonometry and Mathjax  +1  Care to try my Uber EE challenge or the other?